# ((MFC C++) || (win Form application C++) || (MFC C#) || (win Form application C#))

Tags: c#, gui, mfc, c++

Что на ваше усмотрение наиболее удобно для создания программы с GUI интерфейсом windows?
Пробовал работать с windows form application C++, но мне это показалось несколько неудобно, а как передать тип данных array<Char> в пользовательский класс, я вообще не разобрался. Программу написал, но в итоге получился не код, а нечитабельная лапша.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется, лучше всего C#/WPF.

Winforms устарели, а C++/CLI вообще ужас, которого стоит избегать как огня. MFC тоже не новейшая технология.

Поэтому:

- если C++, то лучше всего Qt, потом MFC, Winforms c С++/CLI не берите.
- если C#, лучше всего WPF, потом Winforms.
- комбинации MFC/C#, насколько мне известно, не существует.